# Reflow oven - resistive heating element or infra-red

Tags: reflow

I'm looking at making a reflow oven and have just found out the toaster oven I have bought uses a standard conduction heating element rather than infra-red. The knob used for temperature control goes up to 250˚C - so should be high enough for the lead-free solder-paste I have access to. Will using a reflow oven with a standard heating element work? Most of the guides I can find on the 'net talk about infra-red versions.

Comment: Shouldn't make much difference, but try for about 1500 watts.

Comment: Also, I recommend starting with lead solder, unless there's a regulatory reason to do otherwise.  It's much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Worked OK for me.

Don't count on that 250C being accurate. I used a PT1k and a microcontroller to get a reasonably accurate temperature profile.